# Adding another control to Manipulate[MatrixPlot[matrix]] to take specific part of matrix

Tags: manipulate

I got matrix, let's say, 100 rows and I would like to plot only 10-rows window of it.

Is it possible to add a slide control to Manipulate[] window so to shift 10-row "window" interactively?

I trying Manipulate[MatrixPlot[matrix[[x ;; x + 10]]], {x,0,100}], but that's not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mistakes:

- Element index starts from 1, not 0
- Manipulate control x should run with step 1
- Manipulate control x should run with up to 100 - 10 = 90, other wise you will exceed the max index

Here is a correct version

```
m = RandomReal[1, {100, 10}];
Manipulate[MatrixPlot[m[[1 + x ;; x + 10]]], {x, 0, 90, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to make the above manipulate interactive a la .cdf?

Comment: wow, thanks for your prompt answer!

Comment: @WalkingRandomly yes, definitely. Using **Top Menu >> Deploy >> ...**

Comment: @Vitaliy Yes I know that :) What I meant was 'why not do it in this answer?'

Comment: @WalkingRandomly Nasser is correct. I do not think this site supports java script plug-ins. BTW I replied to your graph comment. I'd be curious to know if you had a chance to try it and if you was able to complete building your huge twitter graph. Thanks for the comments guys ;)